# Handling urllib2's timeout? - Python

Tags: python, timeout, urllib2, urllib

I'm using the timeout parameter within the urllib2's urlopen.

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.org', timeout=1)
```

How do I tell Python that if the timeout expires a custom error should be raised?

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: [`timeout` parameter doesn't limit neither the *total* connection time nor *total* read (response) time.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32684677/4279)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There are very few cases where you want to use `except:`. Doing this captures *any* exception, which can be hard to debug, and it captures exceptions including `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterupt`, which can make your program annoying to use..

At the very simplest, you would catch [`urllib2.URLError`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError):

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout = 1)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    raise MyException("There was an error: %r" % e)
```

The following should capture the specific error raised when the connection times out:

```
import urllib2
import socket

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout = 1)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    # For Python 2.6
    if isinstance(e.reason, socket.timeout):
        raise MyException("There was an error: %r" % e)
    else:
        # reraise the original error
        raise
except socket.timeout, e:
    # For Python 2.7
    raise MyException("There was an error: %r" % e)
```

Comment: This will not work in Python 2.7, as URLError does not catch socket.timeout anymore

Comment: @TalWeiss thanks, added an additional catch for `socket.timeout`

Comment: As for Python 2.7.5 timeouts are caught by urllib2.URLError.

Comment: @dbr Thanks, moreover it should be `hasattr(e,'reason') and isinstance(e.reason, socket.timeout)` as `HttpError` at least doesn't have a `reason` attribute in Python 2.6.

Comment: I don't understand Tal and Nicolas's comments, but `socket.timeout` works for me with Python 2.7.6.

Comment: For what it's worth, with python 2.6.6 a timeout trying to connect seems to result in the `urllib2.URLError`. A timeout while reading the response from a slow server seems to result in `socket.timeout`. So overall, catching both allows you to distinguish these cases.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and I just could handle TimeoutException with 'urllib2.URLError' instead of 'socket.timeout'

Answer (score 20):

In Python 2.7.3:

```
import urllib2
import socket

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout = 1)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print type(e)    #not catch
except socket.timeout as e:
    print type(e)    #catched
    raise MyException("There was an error: %r" % e)
```