# Skip URL if timeout

Tags: python, sockets, exception, timeout, urllib2

I have a list of URL's

I am using the following to retrieve their contents:

```
for url in url_list:
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
    resp_page = resp.read()
    print resp_page
```

When there is a timeout, the program just crashes. I just want to read the next URL if there is a `socket.timeout: timed out`. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: For a similar problem see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712524/handling-urllib2s-timeout-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that by "crashes" you mean "raises a URLError", as described by the [`urllib2.urlopen` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen). See the [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) section of the Python Tutorial.

```
for url in url_list:
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        print "Bad URL or timeout"
        continue # skips to the next iteration of the loop
    resp_page = resp.read()
    print resp_page
```

Answer (score 7):

Although there already is an answer, I'd like to point out that `URLlib2` might not be the sole responsible with this behavior.

As pointed out [here](http://heyman.info/2010/apr/22/python-urllib2-timeout-issue/) (and as it also seems based on the problem description), the exception may belong to the `socket` library.

In that case just add another `except`:

```
import socket

try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
except urllib2.URLError:
    print "Bad URL or timeout"
except socket.timeout:
    print "socket timeout"
```

Comment: Downvoting with no explanation is not really useful, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to catch the timeout exception.  I don't get a socket.timeout message that you do.

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.2")
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
except urllib2.URLError:
    print "Timeout!"
```

Obviously, you need to have a URL that will actually timeout (127.0.0.2 may not on your box).