# How to get the instance type of an Exception?

Tags: python, exception

I have this code:

```
try:
    self.client.post(url, data, self.cookies, headers, auth, jsonrpc)
    self.status  = self.client.status
    self.mytime  = self.client.time
    self.text    = self.client.text
    self.length  = len(self.text)
except urllib2.URLError, error:
    print error
    self.exception = True
    self.urrlib2   = True
    if isinstance(error.reason, socket.timeout):
        self.timeout = True
```

But sometimes I get exceptions printing out like this:

```
URLError in POST > reason=The read operation timed out > <urlopen error The read operation timed out>
```

These are handled by the `except urllib2.URLError`. They should pass the `if isinstance(error.reason, socket.timeout)` test, but they do not.

So I would like to know what `instance` this exception is. How can I do this?

Comment: `type()` gives you a string representation of an object's type or class.

Comment: So you mean I should do `type(error)` here? I have to modify my code, and the exception will take several hours to appear ... Or is it `type(error.reason)` ?

Comment: `print type(error.reason)` will help you diagnose what type it is; not much of an answer, hence just a comment.

Comment: why not!? That *is* the answer (if it works). So I will test it and accept it as answer ...

Comment: Erm, not a string representation, a type object. Sorry, need some more sleep there.

Comment: AttributeError: 'timeout' object has no attribute 'reason'

Comment: @ATOzTOA: `urllib2.URLError` objects have a `.reason` attribute. That is what the exception handling is catching.

Comment: @gonvaled Your code should work, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712524/handling-urllib2s-timeout-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`type()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) returns the type of an object.

You could use `print type(error.reason)` to diagnose what type of object `reason` is in this case.

Comment: I have found that it is of instance `ssl.SSLError`. I wonder what this has to do with `urllib2.URLError`

Comment: Mmm. I see this http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html. `ssl.SSLError` is of subtype `socket.error` which is of subtype `IOError`. I do not know why it goes through the `except urllib2.URLError, error` code.

Comment: @gonvaled: The `urllib2` code catches that exception, then raises `URLError(originalexception)`, and that argument is stored as `.reason`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import sys

try:
    self.client.post(url, data, self.cookies, headers, auth, jsonrpc)
    self.status  = self.client.status
    self.mytime  = self.client.time
    self.text    = self.client.text
    self.length  = len(self.text)
except urllib2.URLError, error:
    print error
    self.exception = True
    self.urrlib2   = True

    errno, errstr = sys.exc_info()[:2]
    if errno == socket.timeout:
        print "There was a timeout"
        self.timeout = True
```