# Terminating try block in python after n seconds

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing, signals

I am trying to impose a TimeoutException on a try statement after n seconds. I have found a library which handles this called signal which would be perfect but I'm running into an error I have a hard time getting around. ([This similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507358/python-time-a-try-except) is answered with the signal library.)

This is the boiled down code representing the problem:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def main():
    listOfLinks = []
    threadpool = Pool(2)
    info = threadpool.starmap(processRunSeveralTimesInParallel,zip(enumerate(listOfLinks)))
    threadpool.close()

def processRunSeveralTimesInParallel(listOfLinks):
    #The following is pseudo code representing what I would like to do:
    loongSequenceOfInstructions()
    for i in range(0,10):
        try for n seconds:
            doSomething(i)
        except (after n seconds):
            handleException()

    return something
```

When implementing [the above question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47147501/7746961) with the signal library, I get the following error:

```
File "file.py", line 388, in main
    info = threadpool.starmap(processRunSeveralTimesInParallel,zip(enumerate(listOfLinks)))
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "file.py", line 193, in processRunSeveralTimesInParallel
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.8/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Any idea how to cap the time just on a try block within a method run as a thread? Thank you!

Important information:

- I am using the multiprocessing library to run several processes at the same time in parallel. From the error statement above, I suspect that the signal and multiprocessing libraries conflict.
- The methods in the try statement are [selenium (find_element_by_xpath) methods](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). However there are no timeout arguments available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Newly Updated Answer**

If you are a way of looking for timing out without using signals, here is one way. First, since you are using threading, let's make it explicit and let's use the `concurrent.futures` module, which has a lot of flexibility.

When a "job" is submitted to the pool executor, a `Future` instance is returned immediately without blocking until a `result` call is made on that instance. You can specify a `timeout` value such that if the result is not available within the timeout period, an exception will be thrown. The idea is to pass to the worker thread the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance and for it to run the critical piece of code that must be completed within a certain time period within its own worker thread. A `Future` instance will be created for that timed code but this time the `result` call will specify a `timeout` value:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
import time


def main():
    listOfLinks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    futures = []
    """
    To prevent timeout errors due to lack of threads, you need at least one extra thread
    in addition to the ones being created here so that at least one time_critical thread
    can start. Of course, ideally you would like all the time_critical threads to be able to
    start without waiting. So, whereas the minimum number of max_workers would be 6 in this
    case, the ideal number would be 5 * 2 = 10.
    """
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        # pass executor to our worker
        futures = [executor.submit(processRunSeveralTimesInParallel, tuple, executor) for tuple in enumerate(listOfLinks)]
        for future in futures:
            result = future.result()
            print('result is', result)


def processRunSeveralTimesInParallel(tuple, executor):
    link_number = tuple[0]
    link = tuple[1]
    # long running sequence of instructions up until this point and then
    # allow 2 seconds for this part:
    for i in range(10):
        future = executor.submit(time_critical, link, i)
        try:
            future.result(timeout=2) # time_critical does not return a result other than None
        except TimeoutError:
            handle_exception(link, i)
    return link * link_number


def time_critical(link, trial_number):
    if link == 'd' and trial_number == 7:
        time.sleep(3) # generate a TimeoutError


def handle_exception(link, trial_number):
    print(f'There was a timeout for link {link}, trial number {trial_number}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
result is
result is b
result is cc
There was a timeout for link d, trial number 7.
result is ddd
result is eeee
```

**Using Threading and Multiprocessing**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
import os
import time


def main():
    listOfLinks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
    futures = []
    cpu_count = os.cpu_count()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count) as thread_executor, ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count) as process_executor:
        # pass executor to our worker
        futures = [thread_executor.submit(processRunSeveralTimesInParallel, tuple, process_executor) for tuple in enumerate(listOfLinks)]
        for future in futures:
            result = future.result()
            print('result is', result)


def processRunSeveralTimesInParallel(tuple, executor):
    link_number = tuple[0]
    link = tuple[1]
    # long running sequence of instructions up until this point and then
    # allow 2 seconds for this part:
    for i in range(10):
        future = executor.submit(time_critical, link, i)
        try:
            future.result(timeout=2) # time_critical does not return a result other than None
        except TimeoutError:
            handle_exception(link, i)
    return link * link_number


def time_critical(link, trial_number):
    if link == 'd' and trial_number == 7:
        time.sleep(3) # generate a TimeoutError


def handle_exception(link, trial_number):
    print(f'There was a timeout for link {link}, trial number {trial_number}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
result is
result is b
result is cc
There was a timeout for link d, trial number 7.
result is ddd
result is eeee
result is fffff
result is gggggg
result is hhhhhhh
result is iiiiiiii
result is jjjjjjjjj
```

**Multiprocessing Exclusively**

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import time


def main():
    listOfLinks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
    futures = []
    workers = os.cpu_count() // 2
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as process_executor:
        # pass executor to our worker
        futures = [process_executor.submit(processRunSeveralTimesInParallel, tuple) for tuple in enumerate(listOfLinks)]
        for future in futures:
            result = future.result()
            print('result is', result)


def processRunSeveralTimesInParallel(tuple):
    link_number = tuple[0]
    link = tuple[1]
    # long running sequence of instructions up until this point and then
    # allow 2 seconds for this part:
    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target=time_critical, args=(link, i))
        p.start()
        p.join(timeout=2) # don't block for more than 2 seconds
        if p.exitcode is None: # subprocess did not terminate
            p.terminate() # we will terminate it
            handle_exception(link, i)
    return link * link_number


def time_critical(link, trial_number):
    if link == 'd' and trial_number == 7:
        time.sleep(3) # generate a TimeoutError


def handle_exception(link, trial_number):
    print(f'There was a timeout for link {link}, trial number {trial_number}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
result is
result is b
result is cc
There was a timeout for link d, trial number 7.
result is ddd
result is eeee
result is fffff
result is gggggg
result is hhhhhhh
result is iiiiiiii
result is jjjjjjjjj
```

Comment: Hi Booboo, thank you very much for your insightful answer! However, I am not sure this solves my problem. I slightly edited the ```processRunSeveralTimesInParallel``` to make what I'm trying to do more clear. The issue is that I am already in a thread when running the try block. It seems to me that the ```ThreadPoolExecutor``` submits jobs as entire methods. My ```processRunSeveralTimesInParallel``` method is quite long and the try block is a smallish part of it. Any idea how to cap the time just on a try block within a method run as a thread? Your help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer. The logic is even simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the update Booboo. I am trying to put the try/except blocks in a for loop but the loop acts very strangely. It only iterates through the first pass. Do you know how to make ```result = future.result(timeout=2)``` run in a for loop? Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer yet again. I don't what difficulty you could have had putting the Future creation and awaiting completion in a loop. Here I am passing the loop index so it only times out for one of the attempts.

Comment: Yes, that last comment was due to an error on my part. Thank you so much for your help Booboo. You really got me out of this pickle. Have a good one

Comment: Hi Booboo, I was wondering how you would account for the case where you have ```len(listOfLinks) == 1000```. Only having N CPUs (N being much smaller than 1000) is there a way of setting your ```max_workers``` so that it only using N/2 CPUs at a time for threads and so that the other N/2 CPUs may be used as an additional process for the timing of the try block? I browsed the documentation but haven't found anything. Thank you!

Comment: First, let's not confuse mult-threading (`ThreadPoolExecutor`) with multiprocessing (`ProcessPoolExecutor`), the former suitable for I/O bound work only due to limitations posed by Python's Global Interpreter Lock that prevents concurrent execution of Python byte code in separate threads. With multiple *processes*, there is no point in specifying a value for `max_workers` that exceeds the number of CPUs you have but with lightweight threads that is not the case although there might be a number where you start to lose efficiency. (... more)

Comment: So, your question about allocation of CPUs is really only relevant for multiprocessing. And remember, you have a requirement that ideally the number of threads should be twice the length of your `listOfLinks`. If it is fewer than the minimum number I have set forth, then you will get timeout errors due to the lack of threads. You can always break the list into smaller lists to keep the pool size to a reasonable number. It also sounds like you should be using multiprocessing at least for part of your processing that is CPU intensive.

Comment: So, if in the worst case scenario if everything had to be run using multiprocessing and you had 8 processors, I would break my `listOfLinks` list up into smaller lists of length 4 (8 // 2.,  I would then have 4 processors to execute `processRunSeveralTimesInParallel` and 4 processors to execute `time_critical`. If only  `time_critical` were CPU intensive, I would have `main` also create a `ProcessorPoolExecutor` instance and pass it as the argument to `processRunSeveralTimesInParallel`. You should now use no more than 8 threads in your thread pool but you don't need to break up your list.

Comment: You have just demystified a lot of what I've been trying to do. Once again, thank you so much for generously taking the time to answer my questions. Best

Comment: I've updated answer with example showing threading and multiprocessing. Using multiprocessing exclusively is not as simple as I had suggested: you cannot pass the `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance as an argument to a subprocess. I will have to come up with an alternate later.

Comment: Any chance you have a "buymeacoffee" account? I'd really like to make it up to you!

Comment: It was my pleasure if I was able to help at all. Stay healthy!

Comment: Thanks again for everything Booboo. Have a good week!