# python urllib2 try to open url until it works

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2

I need to gather some data from a website, actually it is some text for further analysis. Since I am no expert in web scraping, I did the first step of getting urls with the documents I need. The problem is, that sometimes I can get the documents, but sometimes I get connection time out error. So I want a way for trying until I can get the website response, this is what I have:

```
from html2text import *
import urllib2
import html2text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

id = 1
with open("urls.txt") as f:
    for url in f:
        print url
        html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        with codecs.open("documentos/" + str(id) + ".txt", "w", "utf-8-sig") as temp:
            temp.write(soup.get_text())
        id += 1
```

where urls.txt has the desired urls, an example of an url:

How can I achieve this? I could handle it if I only needed 10 documents, but I need more than 500... So I cannot do it manually.

In summary:

Sometimes I can get the documents, sometimes I cannot due to timeout, I want python to try until it CAN get the document...

Answer (score 1):

You would have to better structure your function for fetching site info a bit. Once you have that function, you can use a [retry decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib2.urlopen()`'s timeout argument like this :[Handling urllib2's timeout? - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712524/handling-urllib2s-timeout-python),
and and a retry decorator.