# How to send a repeat request in urllib2.urlopen in Python if the first call is just stuck?

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I am making a call to a URL in Python using urllib2.urlopen in a while(True) loop

My URL keeps changing every time (as there is a change in a particular parameter of the URL every time).

My code look as as follows:

```
def get_url(url):
    '''Get json page data using a specified API url'''
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = str(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
    page = json.loads(data)
    return page
```

I am calling the above method from the main function by changing the url every time I make the call.

What I observe is that after few calls to the function, suddenly (I don;t know why), the code gets stuck at the statement

```
response = urlopen(url)
```

and it just waits and waits...

How do I best handle this situation?

I want to make sure that if it does not respond within say 10 seconds, I make the same call again.

I read about

```
response = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
```

but then what about the repeated call if this fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many retries you want to attempt, use a try/catch inside a loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        response = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
        break
    except:
        # do something with the error
        pass
# do something with response
data = str(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
...
```

This will silence all exceptions, which may not be ideal (more on that here: [Handling urllib2's timeout? - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712524/handling-urllib2s-timeout-python))

Answer (score 1):

With this method you can retry once.

```
def get_url(url, trial=1):
    try:    
        '''Get json page data using a specified API url'''
        response = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
        data = str(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        page = json.loads(data)
        return page
    except:
        if trial == 1:
            return get_url(url, trial=2)
        else:
            return
```

Comment: @abhishek-shivkumar Did you get a chance to try this code?