# Break urlopen if long expectation

Tags: python

This is a part of my code in Python:

```
url="http://export.finam.ru/very long line"
data = urlopen(url).read()
```

These urls are changing, but they are 100% don't have mistakes.
Sometimes my script freeze at this place. Nothing happens. urlopen cannot get data. No error messages come. Script just waiting for an hours.
How can I break this waiting and start

```
data = urlopen(url).read()
```

again?
Comments showed that timeout parameter will solve my problem. How can I use it to restart

```
data = urlopen(url).read()
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Comment: You can set the timeout parameter on `urlopen`. Add the timeout parameter in my suggested dupe and handle it in accordance with the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling urllib2's timeout? - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712524/handling-urllib2s-timeout-python)

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword it's not a duplicate of that; requests come with a specific timeout parameter, there's no need to treat it as some generic function that you want to wrap in some timeout - it's done for you

Comment: Yes I didn't know about it. You may post it as an answer I think.

Comment: There is no timeout parameter in this function urllib.urlopen(url[, data[, proxies[, context]]])

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword I've flagged as a duplicate of another question. There is no need for me to answer it, I'm hoping for it to be closed as a dupe because all the info needed already exists

Comment: @Kosmonavt why are you using the base urllib? You haven't mentioned that anywhere in the question, I already took a guess to work out it was urllib2. On that theme, is there a reason you're not using `requests`?